# Can't download file from FTP if firewall is on using wininet.dll in Word Template VBA

Tags: vba, ftp, ms-word, wininet

I have created Word Template Add-In (.dtom). It downloads a file from server using FTP. It is working fine if my firewall is off. It doesn't allow to download if Firewall is on. In some cases, Firewall is set using Antivirus.

This is my code which works fine if firewall is off.

```
'Add DLL runtime

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet.dll" _
(ByRef dwflags As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal sAgent As String, _
    ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
    ByVal sProxyName As String, _
    ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
    ByVal sServerName As String, _
    ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
    ByVal sUsername As String, _
    ByVal sPassword As String, _
    ByVal lService As Long, _
    ByVal lFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
    ByVal hConnect As Long, _
    ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
    ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
    ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
    ByVal dwflags As Long, _
    ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
    ByVal hInet As Long) As Long

Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE         As Long = &H8000000 


Public Sub downloadFile()   
    If (fileExists = True) Then
        Kill folderLocation
    End If
    strRemoteFile = "/MyFile.xml"
    strLocalFile = folderLocation
    strHost = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"

    lngPort = 21
    strUser = "myuser"
    strPass = "mypassword"
    'usage
    'FtpDownload "/TEST/test.html", "c:\test.html", "ftp.server.com", 21, "user", "password"
    Dim hOpen   As Long
    Dim hConn   As Long

    hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
    hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 2)

    If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
        Debug.Print "done"
    Else
        Debug.Print "fail"
    End If

    InternetCloseHandle hConn
    InternetCloseHandle hOpen
End Sub
```

Please suggest me how to download if Firewall is on. Also suggest if anyother way which can work for firewall problem. (Ex. In Mac VBA we can download file using Curl command in MacScript which can execute from VBA)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the passive FTP mode:

```
InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 2)
```

the `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` is `&H08000000`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/api-flags

---

The `InternetConnect` defaults to the active mode, which is mostly unusable, when a firewall or a NAT is involved.

See my article on the [Active and Passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand why you need to use the passive mode.